# Trouble getting the angle between tapped point and midpoint x-axis line

Tags: ios

I've opted for a picture, which I think may better describe the angle I'm trying to calculate:

[image]

`CGPoint P2` is anywhere where the user tapped, and `CGPoint P1` always has its `P1.y = P2.y` and `P1.x = self.view.bounds.size.width/2`.

I was wondering how I could try to calculate the angle between the two points given that I want to base the angle on the half way x-axis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle is:

```
90-arctan((self.view.bounds.size.height - P2.y)/(P2.x - self.view.bounds.size.width/2))
```

(It will be positive at the right of the line, negative at the left. If you always want it positive, use `abs()`)

What I'm doing is basically setting the origin at the bottom center of the screen, then calculating the slope of the line from the origin to P2. Then `arctan` gives the angle of the line respect to the X axis. Then you do `90-arctan(..)` to make it respect the Y axis.

Alternatively you can use this formula, which is the same with the axes already flipped.

```
arctan((P2.x - self.view.bounds.size.width/2)/(self.view.bounds.size.height - P2.y))
```